# JPA query error because it has a subquery - I don't understand why

Tags: java, jpa

I have this query:

```
public List<Participant> getTop4ScoresFromAStage(EtapaEntity etapaEntity) {
        TypedQuery<Participant> query = connection
                .getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("SELECT a FROM Participant as a WHERE a.punctaj >=" +
                        "(SELECT DISTINCT a.punctaj FROM a ORDER BY a.punctaj DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3)" +
                        "WHERE a.etapaEntity = :etapaEntity ORDER BY a.punctaj DESC", Participant.class)
                .setParameter("etapaEntity", etapaEntity);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

and I have an error on the first ORDER BY clause.

The error is:

```
')', ',', <join>, AS, GROUP, HAVING, IN or WHERE expected, got 'ORDER'
```

and I don't understand why. This query works fine in Postgres.

Can anybody help me understand why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

//edit: I tried my code like this (after the suggestion of KebabProgrammer)

```
public List<Participant> getTop4ScoresFromAStage(EtapaEntity etapaEntity) {
        TypedQuery<Participant> query = connection
                .getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("SELECT a FROM Participant as a WHERE a.punctaj >=" +
                        "(SELECT DISTINCT b.punctaj FROM Participant as b ORDER BY b.punctaj DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3)" +
                        "WHERE a.etapaEntity = :etapaEntity ORDER BY a.punctaj DESC", Participant.class)
                .setParameter("etapaEntity", etapaEntity);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

and I get the same error.

Comment: I think your issue is here `SELECT a FROM Participant as a WHERE a.punctaj`, you have a column called `a` and then you are then declaring your table as `FROM Participants as a`. MySQL doesn't know what you are trying to order, so I think you need to fix your declarations, and then you shouldn't have any issues

Comment: @KebabProgrammer I'm using Postgres :) Also, can you check my edit? I've updated my code.

Comment: Execute first the subquery :

`SELECT DISTINCT a.punctaj FROM a ORDER BY a.punctaj DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3`

Then execute the second query :

    SELECT a FROM Participant as a WHERE a.punctaj >= :punctaj WHERE
    a.etapaEntity = :etapaEntity ORDER BY a.punctaj DESC

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using where clause twice `WHERE a.punctaj` in the first line and `WHERE a.etapaEntity` in the third line. Second where should be replaced with `AND` or `OR` as the case may be